# Ambientes virtuales en Python

Tags: python

Entiendo cómo funcionan los ambientes virtuales en Pyhton, y su utilidad, pero mi pregunta es:
Una vez desarrollada la aplicación en su ambiente virtual, cuando llevo la aplicación a poducción, ¿se debe armar nuevamente un ambiente virtual (copia del de desarrollo), y activarlo para la ejecución de la aplicación?
¿Cuál es la forma correcta de llevar el ambiente de desarrollo a producción?
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Imagina un ambiente virtual como un laboratorio en el cual se desarrolla medicina. En tal laboratorio habrá un monto de cosas para hacer pruebas y mantener la medicina segura, una vez se quiera poner a la venta solo debes de verificar que todo esté bien y empaquetar la medicina para su distribución. Lo mismo pasa en este caso, aunque depende de como sea tu proyecto. Si lo subes a github deberás de subirlo todo ignorando la carpeta de tu entorno virtual (crear un entorno virtual o no ya dependerá de quien use tu codigo) si por el contrario deseas hacer un exe solo debes de agrupar lo necesario

Comment: La práctica habitual hoy día para desplegar algo en producción es hacerlo dentro de un contenedor (ej. docker). Un contenedor contiene en una sola imagen el código a desplegar y todas sus dependencias (es decir, todas las bibliotecas necesarias e incluso el intérprete python necesario). Eso le hace totalmente independiente de la máquina en la que se vaya a desplegar. En una misma máquina puedes desplegar muchos contenedores, cada uno con sus bibliotecas y su propio python (incluso una versión diferente en cada contenedor)